# How to get consecutive pairs (based on their Timeslot) of Lessons in Timefold?

Tags: java, spring-boot, constraints, optaplanner, timefold

Based on GitHub project provided by Timefold (https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/technology/java-spring-boot) I want to implement a constraint for the following scenario that can occur in the university:

Let's say that for a specific Day (Monday), we have 7 Timeslots (8AM - 10AM, 10AM - 12AM, ..., 8PM-10PM) and 4 different Lessons to assign in that day. We want to ensure that there is not any gaps (bigger than 2 hours for example) in the schedule for the specific day.

My current attempt is the following:

```
Constraint tooMuchGap(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory){
        // 4 hours gaps between lessons for students in the same day
        //todo solve this problem-> we receive pairs that are not consecutives
        return constraintFactory
                //select each 2 pair of different lessons
                .forEach(Lesson.class)
                .join(Lesson.class,
                        //with the same student group
                        Joiners.equal(Lesson::getStudentGroup),
                        //in the same day
                        Joiners.equal((lesson) -> lesson.getTimeslot().getDayOfWeek()),
                        Joiners.lessThan((lesson -> lesson.getTimeslot().getId())))
                .filter((lesson1, lesson2) -> {
                    
                    Duration between = Duration.between(lesson1.getTimeslot().getEndTime(),
                            lesson2.getTimeslot().getStartTime());
                    return !between.isNegative() && between.compareTo(Duration.ofHours(3)) > 0;
                })
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT)
                //.justifyWith()
                .asConstraint("Too much gap between the courses");
    }
```

For this test case:

```
@Test
    void tooMuchGap(){
        StudentGroup studentGroup = new StudentGroup(1L,"Group1");
        Lesson firstTuesdayLesson = new Lesson(1, "subject1", new Teacher(1L, "Teacher2"), studentGroup, TIMESLOT2, ROOM1);
        Lesson secondTuesdayLesson = new Lesson(2, "subject2", new Teacher(2L, "Teacher1"), studentGroup, TIMESLOT3, ROOM1);
        Lesson thirdTuesdayLesson = new Lesson(3, "subject3", new Teacher(3L, "Teacher3"), studentGroup, TIMESLOT6, ROOM1);
        Lesson fourthTuesdayLesson = new Lesson(4, "subject4", new Teacher(4L, "Teacher3"), studentGroup, TIMESLOT7, ROOM1);
        constraintVerifier.verifyThat(TimetableConstraintProvider::tooMuchGap)
                .given(firstTuesdayLesson, secondTuesdayLesson, thirdTuesdayLesson, fourthTuesdayLesson)
                .penalizesBy(1);
    }
```

I receive the following output:

```
2024-03-13 22:45:12.697  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson1's timeslot: Timeslot(id=2, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=12:00, endTime=14:00)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.707  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson2's timeslot: Timeslot(id=3, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=14:30, endTime=16:30)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.707  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - ----------------------------------
2024-03-13 22:45:12.707  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson1's timeslot: Timeslot(id=2, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=12:00, endTime=14:00)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.707  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson2's timeslot: Timeslot(id=6, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=19:00, endTime=21:00)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.707  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - ----------------------------------
2024-03-13 22:45:12.709  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson1's timeslot: Timeslot(id=3, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=14:30, endTime=16:30)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.709  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson2's timeslot: Timeslot(id=6, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=19:00, endTime=21:00)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.709  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - ----------------------------------
2024-03-13 22:45:12.709  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson1's timeslot: Timeslot(id=2, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=12:00, endTime=14:00)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.709  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson2's timeslot: Timeslot(id=7, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=21:00, endTime=23:00)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.709  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - ----------------------------------
2024-03-13 22:45:12.710  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson1's timeslot: Timeslot(id=3, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=14:30, endTime=16:30)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.710  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson2's timeslot: Timeslot(id=7, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=21:00, endTime=23:00)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.710  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - ----------------------------------
2024-03-13 22:45:12.710  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson1's timeslot: Timeslot(id=6, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=19:00, endTime=21:00)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.710  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - The lesson2's timeslot: Timeslot(id=7, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=21:00, endTime=23:00)
2024-03-13 22:45:12.710  INFO [main           ] - c.t.t.s.TimetableConstraintProvider - ----------------------------------

java.lang.AssertionError: Broken expectation.
        Constraint: com.timetablealgo.testingtimetablealgo.solver/Too much gap between the courses
  Expected penalty: 1 (class java.lang.Integer)
    Actual penalty: 3 (class java.lang.Integer)

  Explanation of score (0hard/-3soft):
    Constraint matches:
        -3soft: constraint (Too much gap between the courses) has 3 matches:
            -1soft: justified with ([Lesson(id=2, subject=subject2, teacher=Teacher(id=2, name=Teacher2, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=1, year=null, name=Group1, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=2, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=12:00, endTime=14:00), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null)), Lesson(id=5, subject=subject3, teacher=Teacher(id=3, name=Teacher3, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=1, year=null, name=Group1, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=6, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=19:00, endTime=21:00), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null))])
            -1soft: justified with ([Lesson(id=2, subject=subject2, teacher=Teacher(id=2, name=Teacher2, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=1, year=null, name=Group1, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=2, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=12:00, endTime=14:00), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null)), Lesson(id=6, subject=subject4, teacher=Teacher(id=3, name=Teacher3, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=1, year=null, name=Group1, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=7, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=21:00, endTime=23:00), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null))])
            ...
    Indictments:
        -2soft: indicted with (Lesson(id=2, subject=subject2, teacher=Teacher(id=2, name=Teacher2, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=1, year=null, name=Group1, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=2, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=12:00, endTime=14:00), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null))) has 2 matches:
            -1soft: constraint (Too much gap between the courses)
            -1soft: constraint (Too much gap between the courses)
        -2soft: indicted with (Lesson(id=6, subject=subject4, teacher=Teacher(id=3, name=Teacher3, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=1, year=null, name=Group1, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=7, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=21:00, endTime=23:00), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null))) has 2 matches:
            -1soft: constraint (Too much gap between the courses)
            -1soft: constraint (Too much gap between the courses)
        -1soft: indicted with (Lesson(id=5, subject=subject3, teacher=Teacher(id=3, name=Teacher3, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=1, year=null, name=Group1, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=6, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=19:00, endTime=21:00), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null))) has 1 matches:
            -1soft: constraint (Too much gap between the courses)
        -1soft: indicted with (Lesson(id=3, subject=subject1, teacher=Teacher(id=1, name=Teacher1, preferredTimeslot=null), studentGroup=StudentGroup(id=1, year=null, name=Group1, group=null, semiGroup=null, numberOfStudents=30), type=null, year=null, timeslot=Timeslot(id=3, dayOfWeek=TUESDAY, startTime=14:30, endTime=16:30), room=Room(id=1, name=Room1, capacity=0, type=null, building=null, dotari=null))) has 1 matches:
            -1soft: constraint (Too much gap between the courses)
```

My question is how get **consecutive pairs** (based on their Timeslots) for the evaluation? For this case, I want to get the following pairs only: (Timeslot2 and Timeslot3), (Timeslot3 and Timeslot6), (Timeslot6 and Timeslot7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the definition of `consecutive` is "two timeslots assigned to the same student group on the same day without another timeslot in between them", I would use an `ifNotExists`:

```java
Constraint tooMuchGap(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory){
        // 4 hours gaps between lessons for students in the same day
        return constraintFactory
                //select each 2 pair of different lessons
                .forEach(Lesson.class)
                .join(Lesson.class,
                        //with the same student group
                        Joiners.equal(Lesson::getStudentGroup),
                        //in the same day
                        Joiners.equal((lesson) -> lesson.getTimeslot().getDayOfWeek()),
                        // First starts before second
                        Joiners.lessThan((lesson) -> lesson.getTimeslot().getStartTime())
                )
                .ifNotExists(Lesson.class,
                        //with the same student group
                        Joiners.equal((a,b) -> a.getStudentGroup(), Lesson::getStudentGroup),
                        //in the same day
                        Joiners.equal((a,b) -> a.getTimeslot().getDayOfWeek(), (lesson) -> lesson.getTimeslot().getDayOfWeek()),
                        //is between the two timeslots
                        Joiners.lessThan((a,b) -> a.getTimeslot().getStartTime(), (lesson) -> lesson.getTimeslot().getStartTime()),
                        Joiners.greaterThan((a,b) -> b.getTimeslot().getStartTime(), (lesson) -> lesson.getTimeslot().getStartTime())
                )
                .filter((lesson1, lesson2) -> {
                    
                    Duration between = Duration.between(lesson1.getTimeslot().getEndTime(),
                            lesson2.getTimeslot().getStartTime());
                    return !between.isNegative() && between.compareTo(Duration.ofHours(3)) > 0;
                })
                .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT)
                //.justifyWith()
                .asConstraint("Too much gap between the courses");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you explain how ifNotExists() works in this case so I can understand better, please?

Comment: You can find info about ifNotExists in the Timefold docs: https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/constraints-and-score/score-calculation#constraintStreamsConditionalPropagation ; In this case, our source stream is pairs of lessons (a, b), where a starts before b, and we are checking if there does not exists a c that starts between them (a < c < b). If there no such c, then a and b are consecutive (with a starting before b) (additionally, all these lessons have the same student group and are on the same day).